# On the deflection of really big laser beams

Tags: science-based, hard-science

So, lets say that for one reason  or another, I have a [Petawatt laser](https://lasers.llnl.gov/content/assets/images/science/ps/arc_beamline.jpg) pointed at me, and nothing but a small, high quality, hand mirror to deflect it.

Ignoring the obvious problems of firing a Petawatt laser in the open air, could I deflect this laser with my hand mirrior? If not, what could I expect to experience from said laser hitting me, and what would a mirror need to be constructed out of to deflect said laser.

Comment: If you could clarify what worldbuilding objective you are trying to achieve here, you may avoid closure for not being about worldbuilding. As is, this appears to be a physics question, and not one trying to build something.

Comment: Yes, but not for very long. You could probably last from a microsecond up to maybe even a millisecond, depending on how focused the beam is and how much of its power is lost in the air on the way to your mirror.

Comment: Try asking on the [Physics.se] SE for real-world answers.

Comment: Would you specify pulse duration? A petawatt is 10^15 watts. If it only shines for an femttosecond (10^-15 seconds), total power is only 1 joule. If it is a CW (continuous wave) laser, well, that's another matter.

Comment: For what might work in fiction, see [my answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/71112/defending-against-directed-gamma-ray-weaponry/71253#71253) to an existing post on the subject.  Some of the other answers to that question also give details about what’s wrong with mirrors, so you could consider this a duplicate.

Comment: consider to choose between two tags  science-based or hard-science, and consider not to use hard-science in the case. Consider to add information as wave length and duration of pulse and size of the beam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even assuming your mirror is made from something absolutely perfectly suited to reflecting the laser beam, defect-free and absorbing only 1/10<sup>12</sup>th of the 10<sup>15</sup> watts in your laser beam, you will feel like you were hit by a truck — light has momentum.

Specifically, 1 Petawatt / (speed of light) = 3,335,640.95 newtons… actually, that's not a truck. 340 tons is what you get if you stack three tanks on a blue whale.

Comment: The comment on duration makes me wonder how 340 tons would feel if you only had it on you for for a femtosecond.

Comment: I doubt your nerve impulses would work fast enough to "feel" anything before you are a fine mist on the wall........

Comment: @JDługosz it would feel like a broken glass in your hand, at least in this scenario...

Comment: @Thucydides one joule won't turn a human body into a mist.  The totql energy limits the amount of damage that could be done.

Answer (score 3):

Even at the most reflective materials we know, [dielectric mirrors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_mirror), can only reflect about 99.999% of the light that hits them. That means 10 GW of the Petawatt laser is absorbed as heat. According to the [order of magnitude table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(power)) that is more than the largest nuclear power plant in the world **Released as heat right in front of you**. Dielectric mirrors can only have such a high performance at very specific wavelengths, but that should be possible with a laser. By comparison, an aluminium mirror would absorb an amount of power comparable to the US power consumption at most wavelengths.